# How to do sort + infinite scroll in Next.js App Router?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

I'm using Nextjs 14. I have sorted and paginated data coming from an HTTP API. I would like to

- keep the sort state in the URL query params and change the sort by navigating to a URL with different query params
- upon changing the query params, load the first page of data with the correct sorting,
- upon clicking a "load more" button, append the next page of data

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to do this with server components + server actions.

Here is a simplified example of what I have so far:

(imagine that the `/api/data` endpoint returns JSON in the format `{ data: [...], meta: { offset, limit, hasNextPage, sortDir } }`)

**page.jsx**

```
async function fetchNextPage(currentState) {
  "use server"

  const { data, meta } = currentState

  const response = await fetch(
    `/api/data?offset=${meta.offset + meta.limit}&sortDir=${meta.sortDir}`,
  ).then((res) => res.json())

  return {
    data: [...data, ...response.data],
    meta: response.meta,
  }
}

export default async function ServerComponent({ searchParams }) {
  const initialData = await fetch(
    `/api/data?offset=0&sortDir=${searchParams.sortDir ?? "asc"}`,
  ).then((res) => res.json())

  return <ClientComponent initialData={initialData} fetchNextPage={fetchNextPage} />
}
```

**ClientComponent.jsx**

```
"use client"

export default function ClientComponent({ initialData, fetchNextPage }) {
  const [{ data, meta }, loadMore] = useFormState(fetchNextPage, initialData)

  return (
    <div>
      <Link href={{ query: { sortDir: "desc" } }}>Sort desc</Link>

      {/* display data */}

      {meta.hasNextPage && <button onClick={_ => loadMore()}>Load more</button>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I click on the "Sort desc" button, the server component correctly gets re-rendered with the new `searchParams` and passes new `initialData` to the client component, but of course the `useFormState` doesn't reset its internal state based on the new prop, so the previous data is still displayed.

What is the best way to achieve my goal using server components + server actions? Is there an idiomatic solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a key on the client component that depends on the query parameters. When the key changes, React will unmount the old component instance and mount a new one, resetting its state.

ClientComponent :

```
"use client"

export default function ClientComponent({ initialData, fetchNextPage, sortDir }) {
  const [{ data, meta }, loadMore] = useFormState(fetchNextPage, initialData)

  return (
    <div key={sortDir}>
      <Link href={{ query: { sortDir: sortDir === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc' } }}>
        Sort {sortDir === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc'}
      </Link>

      {/* display data */}

      {meta.hasNextPage && <button onClick={_ => loadMore()}>Load more</button>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And in your server component, pass the `sortDir` as a prop to the `ClientComponent`:

```
export default async function ServerComponent({ searchParams }) {
  const sortDir = searchParams.sortDir ?? 'asc';
  const initialData = await fetch(
    `/api/data?offset=0&sortDir=${sortDir}`,
  ).then((res) => res.json())

  return <ClientComponent initialData={initialData} fetchNextPage={fetchNextPage} sortDir={sortDir} />
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can even put the `key` straight on `<ClientComponent />` without passing `sortDir` as a prop and it works as expected.